# Hive query join with string as datatype

Tags: sql, string, join, hive

I have two tables in hive and trying to perform a join:

Table A:

```
id  ord_time          
84  10:00:00      
84  12:00:00      
84  15:00:00 
84  4:00:00
```

Data types:

```
Id  : int
ord_time : String
```

Table B:

```
id  time_desc   beg_tm        end_tm
84  Late Night  00:00:00      04:59:59
84  Break Fast  05:00:00      10:29:59
84  Dinner      16:00:00      20:59:59        
84  Lunch       11:00:00      13:59:59
84  Snack       14:00:00      15:59:59
```

Data types:

```
Id  : int
time_desc : String
beg_tm : String
end_tm : String
```

Query :

```
Select a.ord_time,b.id,b.time_desc,b.beg_tm,b.end_tm
from Table A a,Table B b
where a.id = b.id
and a.ord_time between b.beg_tm and b.end_tm
```

When I ran the above query Result was Null.

I want the output to be:

```
id  ord_time    time_desc
84  10:00:00    BreakFast
84  12:00:00    Lunch
84  15:00:00    Snack
84  04:00:00    Late Night
```

Comment: Are there leading or trailing whitespace characters in your time data? Also I notice one table has no leading zeroes, but the other does (that won't work)

Answer (score 0):

Between also didnt work for me. Then I thought

```
name between "a" and "b"
```

is equivalent to

```
name >="a" and name <="b"
```

So I tried this. And it worked for me. Try for your case. Hope it works for you.